# How to replace all backslashes in a dataframe column / pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a dataframe column's any '\' values with empty.

the dataframe column

```
name
jack\\\`s ltd
jack & co \
jack\'s kitchen
```

I'm able to get the rows with `df[df['name'].str.contains('\\\\')]` but when I used
`df['name'].replace('\\\\', '', inplace=True)`, nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)
2. Use backslashes to escape each backslash (essentially doubling the number of backslashes).
3. Per comment: `regex=None` (if not passed) is default for `replace` and `str.replace` and `regex=True` is default for [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). For example, you can do: `df[df['name'].str.contains("\\\\", regex=False)]` and that will return only the one row.

**To Remove ALL backslashes in the specified column, use:**

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\\', '') #this will replace ALL backslashes

    name
0   jack`s ltd
1   jack & co
2   jack's kitchen
```

So, `str.replace` removes PART of a string while `replace` looks for the ENTIRE string, that is unless you pass `regex=True`, which changes how each of the methods work:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\\\\', '') #this will replace two consecutive backslashes.
```

OR

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\\\\\\', '') #this will replace three consecutive backslashes.

    name
0   jack`s ltd
1   jack & co \
2   jack\'s kitchen
```

Comment: thank you. How to replace all '\' (no matter how many) to empty.

Comment: @Osca `df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\\', '')`

Comment: why `df[df['name'].str.contains("\\\\")]` returns all rows with '\' no matter how many time it repeats. But `df['name']  = df['name'].str.replace(r'\\\\', '')` replaced two consecutive '\' only ?

Comment: @Osca see updated answer. I have included links to the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace(r'\\\\', '')
```

Comment: Don't pass `inplace=True`. In your code you are already setting the value back to the column, so you shouldn't use `inplace`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Thats abosultly true. I edited it! Your answer is correct i'll thump up! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:
df["name"]=df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\\\',''))